# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt[3]{3})$ a splitting field over Q?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, splitting-field

Im having trouble showing that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt[3]{3})$ is a splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$.
Im pretty sure it is, since $Irr(\sqrt[3]{3},\mathbb{Q})=x^3-3$ ,which has 2 complex roots.
That shows that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$ cannot be a splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$.
If we wanted to normalize $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3})$ ,we would extend to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},i)$.
Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: Since it doesn't contain the other two roots of $x^3-3$, it is not a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, hence it is not a splitting field of any polynomial.

Comment: @DouglasMolin thank you !